# Hello World ScalaTest Failing: not found: type MyScalatraServlet

Tags: scala, scalatra

I'm trying to get Hello World to get a green test in my hello world scalatra application. The code for the servlet is:

```
package com.graphular.app

import org.scalatra._
import scalate.ScalateSupport

class MyScalatraServlet extends GraphularStack {
  get("/") {
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        Say <a href="hello-scalate">hello to Scalate</a>.
      </body>
    </html>
  }
}
```

It appears to work in the browser and I'm quite happy with that. I wrote the test for it and is as so:

```
import org.scalatra.test.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class MyScalatraServletTests extends ScalatraSuite with FunSuite {
  addServlet(classOf[MyScalatraServlet], "/*")
  test("simple get") {
    get("/") {
      status should equal(200)
      body should include("hi!")
    }
  }
}
```

My `libraryDependencies` are:

```
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalatest" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
```

I thought this was going to work, but instead I keep receiving:

```
[error] /Users/benmorgan/Sites/scala/graphular/src/test/scala/com/graphular/app/MyScalatraServletSpec.scala:7: not found: type MyScalatraServlet
[error]   addServlet(classOf[MyScalatraServlet], "/*")
```

I cannot figure this out for the love of me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the whole code then you forgot the package statement in your test:

```
package com.graphular.app
```

Otherwise you should import the class under test.